# Open Library Covers API Rate Limit

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, oop, caching

I am using PHP / Codeigniter to create a basic library web application. I am retrieving book ISBNs from a MySQL database and displaying the title (from my database) and cover image(from openlibrary.org). I am displaying 10 results per page, however I plan to have a paginated navigation bar on screen so the user can browse multiple pages.

All is working well so far, however looking at the [Open Library Covers API Rate Limiting](https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/covers) it says that;

> The cover access by ids other than CoverID and OLID are rate-limited.
>   Currently only 100 requests/IP are allowed for every 5 minutes.
>
> If any IP tries to access more that the allowed limit, the service
>   will return "403 Forbidden" status.

So, if I am displaying 10 results per page, that's 10 separate requests? And if 10 different users visit my page simultaneously, am I right in thinking that's 100 separate requests, I've exceeded my limit?

What would be the best way to avoid such a scenario? I've thought of two possibilities;

1. Use page caching in Codeigniter by adding `$this->output->cache($n)` in my controller. When I enable this I can see a file is created in `application/cache` containing the 10 records and corresponding images.
2. On page load, perform the API lookup then save the returned data (cover image) into my database. I'm not sure how to do this? Any advice appreciated.

Perhaps there is another way to approach this?

My working code is below if that helps.

**Model**

```
public function itemList() {
    $this->db->select('item_id, item_title, item_isbn');
    $this->db->from('item');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item):?>
    <h3><?php echo $item['item_title'] ?></h3>
    <img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/<?php echo $item['item_isbn']; ?>-M.jpg">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
    $data = array(
        'items' => $this->items_model->itemList()
        );
    $this->load->view('item_view', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the 10 users are on the same IP address (not likely), each will only count as 10 views. A single user would have to open ten tabs and hit the page within the time limit (or refresh the page several times) to exceed the limit.

If they browse 10 pages within 5 minutes, they will see the error in the images. You can either put a message on the page to explain this, or rate limit how often they can update the page. You might try to cache the images on your site and then display them from there (no limits), but that may violate their TOS.

I went to their site, and they also offer all of the images for download. If you serve them from your site, you will completely avoid the rate limits.

Setting up a program to regularly download the images, un-zip them and download the data file on a regular basis should be an relatively easy task using PHP and curl.

Basically, you would:

- Download the six zip archives for each size you want to host (s-Small, m-Medium, and l-Large). They are huge!
- Download the index file.
- Unzip these into temp folders.
- Go through each folder and unzip the .tar files (containing the actual images) into an image folder.
- Import the tab delimited index file into a table in your DB.

The documentation on the index file is sketchy, and it isn't clear if you can use an IBSN number to lookup the image filename. That would take some research and testing to work out.